# On $request->ip() I get "::1" on localhost and my controller does not work with white list IP give me custom error

Tags: laravel, controller, request, ip, whitelist

I have a controller that should give permission to use a resource for one IP. If the IP is an invalid controller should give a customized error "Not correct IP".
But when executing the controller, I keep getting the customized error "Not correct IP".
When I send $request->ip() I get "::1"
I am using localhost
My controller

```
class OhDayHiepController extends Controller
{
   const ALLOWED = [
       "5.5.5.5",
    ];
    public function whiteIP (Request $request)
    {
        abort_unless(in_array($request->ip(), self::ALLOWED), die("Not correct IP"));
        return $request;
    } 
}
```

Why my mistake and why I get ::1. Maybe coz localhost and need custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"::1"` stands for "localhost" in IPv6. You seem to be using IPv4 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx).

I don't know what you're trying to achieve so I can't give you the solution for sure, but you can try already with `"::1"` instead of `"5.5.5.5"` in `ALLOWED`.

There must also be a way to configure your local server to use IPv4 only.